# Merge 2 different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
Table a:
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | 450  |
|  2 | 500  |
|  3 | 550  |
|  4 | 600  |
|  5 | 650  |
+----+------+

Table b:
+----+------+------+
| id | a_id | note |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    2 |   25 |
|  2 |    5 |   10 |
+----+------+------+
```

I need a query that returns a table that consists of every row from `table a` with the notes from `table b`. I want `0` filled in where a note isn't available on a row.  I want it to look like this:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | data | note |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | 450  |    0 |
|  2 | 500  |   25 |     
|  3 | 550  |    0 |
|  4 | 600  |    0 |
|  5 | 650  |   10 |
+----+------+------+
```

How do I do that?

Comment: HINT: use an outer join operation, the join predicate will need to be in the ON clause (not the WHERE clause) to match b.a_id to a.id; in the SELECT list, use an expression such as `IFNULL(b.note,0) AS note`. And add an ORDER BY clause if you want rows returned in a particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.data, coalesce(b.note, 0) as note
from a
left join b on a.id = b.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is called LEFT/RIGHT JOIN. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join?rq=1) question will give you more details about what they are.

Assume you have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON some_condition;
```

Then, its output will contain every row from table a, along with data from table b where the condition is met. For rows where the condition is not met, the columns with data from b will contain null.